# ¿Cómo hacer que aparezcan los datos de dos tablas en sql se visualicen en un formulario en netbeans?

Tags: sql, netbeans-8.0

Quisiera saber si se pueden visualizar los datos de dos tablas en sql, que no están enlazadas como tal,si no que hay una tabla de por medio y estoy llamando las dos tablas por separado, pero los datos de la segunda no se visualizan, solo quiero que se visualice el id de vuelo

```
       public  void datosVuelo() throws SQLException{
           try{ 
               String b;
               Procesos.Buscar_Boleto(txtFolioVoleto.getText());
               b =txtFolioVoleto.getText();
               String sql="Select * from Boleto";
               PreparedStatement pst=conectarBD.getConexion().prepareStatement(sql);
               res = conectarBD.Consulta(sql);

               while(res.next()){
                   if(res.getString(1).equals(b)){
                       String vuelo = res.getString("Id_Vuelo");
                       txtVuelo.setText(vuelo);
                   }   
               }
           }catch(SQLException e){
            }
       }
```

Comment: Has probado con System.out o depurando a ver qué datos te trae la consulta?

Comment: Puedes mostrar cómo están estructuradas tus tablas? Para que te des una idea, tendrías que hacer un `JOIN` entre tus tablas para que te muestre los datos que requieres de ellas. Como nota aparte, no deberías implementar el catch vacío, si tuvieras algún error no sabrías por dónde empezar a buscar.

Comment: * create table Pasajero(
Id_Pasajero varchar(30)  not null,
Id_Estado varchar(30) not null,
Nombre_pasajero nvarchar(30)not null,
ApP_Pasajero nvarchar(30) not null,
ApM_Pasajero nvarchar(30)not null,
Sexo_Pasajero nvarchar(15) not null,
Dia_Nac_Pasajero numeric not null,
Mes_Nac_Pasajero numeric not null,
Año_Nac_Pasajero numeric not null,
Numero_Celular numeric not null,
Correo_Electronico nvarchar(100) not null,
Primary key (Id_Pasajero),
foreign key (Id_Estado) references Estado)*

Comment: Create table Vuelo(
Id_Vuelo varchar(30) not null,
Id_Origen varchar(30) not null,
Id_Destino varchar(30) not null,
Dia_Salida numeric not null,
Mes_Salida numeric not null,
Año_Salida numeric not null,
Dia_Llegada numeric not null,
Mes_Llegada numeric not null,
Año_Llegada numeric not null,
Hora_Salida varchar(10) not null,
Hora_Llegada varchar(10) not null,
Primary key (Id_Vuelo),
foreign key (Id_Origen) references Origen,
foreign key (Id_Destino) references Destino)

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras, mi base de datos es de un aeropuerto y tengo que mostrar los datos de el pasajero y el vuelo, pero las tablas no estan directamente relacionadas, mas bien se relacionan en la tabla de boletos

Comment: Y la estructura de la tabla Boletos? Lo ideal, en lugar de agregar la información como comentario, es que edites tu pregunta.

Comment: Ok, creo que tu consulta sería más o menos así: `select * from boletos b inner join Pasajero P on b.id_pasajero=P.id_pasajero inner join Vuelo v on b.id_vuelo=v.id_vuelo`, aunque estoy suponiendo que en tu tabla boletos las claves foraneas se llaman igual que en tus tablas vuelo y pasajero. Suerte!